# Why isObjectIdOrHexString() doesn't work with the parameter id?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I try to check an id with isObjectIdOrHexString().

```
const testId = "6501a3d18c654e1ece1a5bb0";

    if (!mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString(idtestId ) { 
       console.log("pas bon") 
  } else {
       console.log("bon")
  };
```

This one work.

But when I change(here the road complete) :

````
@Get(':id')  
  async getOneUserById(
    @Param('id') id: string
  ): Promise<ResponseSuccessInterface | ResponseErrorInterface> {

    const user = await this.userService.getOneUserById(id)

if (!mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString(id)) { console.log("pas bon") 
  } else { console.log("bon")};
  console.log("type testid", typeof testId);

    if (!user) {
      console.log("user not found");
      return { error:true, message:"error", status: 404 }
    }
    
    return { data: user, message: "User found", status: 200 }
  }```
When the id is good, no problème. But isend in Postman an another id false. It's crash, doesn't work.
````